# Issue sending headers to Rest API

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

I have to write to an API, and nothing seems to work. When I use [apitester.com](https://apitester.com) it works though. When I use my app, it doesn't. I output the headers and payload and they look the same between the two, so I am assuming I'm doing something wrong. Here is my PHP to send data to the API

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $expired = NULL;
    $funded = TRUE;

    $data = array(
        "email" => $email,
        "expired" => $expired,
        "funded" => $funded
    );

    $url = 'https://my.rest.api';

    $json_string = json_encode($data);

    $headers = array (
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer xxx"    
    );

    $channel = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $statusCode = curl_getInfo($channel, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_exec($channel);   

    http_response_code($statusCode);
    if ( $statusCode != 200 ){
       echo "Data submitted was ".$json_string." Returned status code: {$statusCode} \n".curl_error($channel);
    } else {
       echo $response;
    }
    //I turn the below 2 lines on and off to see what I am actually sending
    // print_r($headers);
    // echo $json_string;

    curl_close($channel);
?>
```

I get the returned status code of "0" on my app, but "200" using the tester. Is there something obviously wrong with the curl options I am sending?

Comment: You should probably close the channel at the end.

Comment: You mean move it below the if / else right? Did that and still get a "0" returned. Code updated above.

Comment: seems  `curl_exec($channel);` is missing in the code. You are getting info over an action that didn't take place.

Comment: Updated code, still no luck

Comment: Check the return value from all functions, esp. include `curl_exec`.

Comment: If I echo out $channel after curl_exec($channel) I get 'Resource ID #2'

Comment: `$channel` is your handle, it will always be a resource. The return value of all functions is the interesting part. `$ret = curl_setopt(...)`, `$ret = curl_exec(...)`. As is in the code provided, you're not checking any of the calls for failure values or expected return values. Hard to know what's awry without first asserting everything operated correctly.

Comment: There's a lot I obviously don't know! How would I begin to check the calls?

Answer (score 1):

If you got status 0, it means that the HTTP request didn't complete at all. You can use the following functions to find out what error happened:

- [curl_errno](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)
- [curl_errstr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errstr.php)

Sidesnotes:

- You're echoing `$response`, but that variable doesn't exist.
- Using `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is a really bad idea. Make sure you remove it before you go to production.

Comment: I updated my code with this if(curl_errno($channel)) {
     echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($channel);
    } and I get 'No Response"

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign is this on some server, or your own machine?

Comment: One strong possibility is that firewall rules prevent you from accessing this API.

Comment: Found a way to use curl_errno. It returns "{"status":400,"message":"Bad arguments: empty email","code":"EmailEmpty"}" however when i output the payload, its clearly sending an email address {"email":"test@test.com","expired":null,"funded":true}